# Why is the addition of a new jQuery function preventing execution of an existing one?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-click-event

I'm struggling to determine why the addition of a new jQuery click function is preventing an existing AJAX call I had from working properly (NOTE: I've double-checked and isolated the addition of the new function as the cause).

The context of the situation is that I have a page which gives the user a word problem, times the user's response and then uses an AJAX call to process the user's answer and display additional suggested answers. This functionality all works. However, when I tweaked my code so that the timer would not begin until after the user clicked a start button (before the timer began when the page loaded), the AJAX code stopped working.

My question is: why would the AJAX call work with the original jQuery timer but not the tweaked jQuery timer code.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the original timer jQuery:

```
    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
    $('#timer').html(count + ' secs.');
        count++;
    },1000);
```

Here is the new timer jQuery that has the added click function:

```
$('#start_answer').click(function(){
    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
        $('#timer').html(count + ' secs.');
        count++;
        },1000);
    $('.cluster_a').addClass("answer_highlight");
    $('.cluster_q').addClass("question_unhighlight");

});
```

Here is the AJAX call:

```
        $('#process_structure').live('click', function () {
        var postData = $('#inputs_structure').serializeArray();
        postData.push({name: 'count', value: count});
        $('#testing').fadeOut('slow');
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "structure_process.php",
            data: $.param(postData),
            success: function(text){
                $('#testing').fadeIn('500', function(){
                    $('#testing').html(text);
                })
            }
        });

        $(this).parent().html('<a class="right_next" href="/structure.php">Do another</a>');

        clearInterval(interval);
        return false;
    })
```

HTML it's applied to:

```
        <div class="problem" id="testing"> <!-- create main problem container -->
        <div class="cluster_q">
            <div class="title"><?php if($switch){; echo $_SESSION['title']; ?></div>
                <div class="summary"><?php echo $_SESSION['problem']; ?></div>
                    <div class="extras"><?php echo 'Categories: ' . $_SESSION['category'][0] . ' | Source: <a href="' . $_SESSION['source'][1] . '">' . $_SESSION['source'][0] . '</a>'; ?> <!--<a href="http://www.engadget.com/2011/01/06/gm-invests-5-million-in-powermat-says-wireless-charging-headed/">Engadget blog post</a>--></div>
            <button id="start_answer">start</button>
        </div>
                    <form method="POST" id="inputs_structure"> 
                        <div class="cluster_a" id="tree_container">
                            <?php acceptTreeTest($num); ?>
                        </div>

                        <table class="basic" id="new_bucket">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="td_alt"></td>
                                <td class="td_alt"><a href="#" id="add_bucket" class="extras">add bucket</a></td>
                                <td class="td_alt"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
        <?php } else{; ?>
            <p>Whoa! You've done every single structure question. Nice work!</p>
            <a href="/structure.php">Start going through them again</a>
            </div> <!-- extra /div close to close the divs if the page goes through the else statement -->
            </div> <!-- extra /div close to close the divs if the page goes through the else statement -->
        <?php }; ?>      
    </div> <!-- closes problem container -->
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML on which this is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the `interval` and `count` variables outside of the click handlers so that they are in scope for the `push` and `clearInterval()` invocations in your code.

```
var count = 0;
var interval;
$('#start_answer').click(function(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        $('#timer').html(count + ' secs.'); 
        // rest of code


$('#process_structure').live('click', function () {
    var postData = $('#inputs_structure').serializeArray();
    postData.push({name: 'count', value: count});
    ...
    clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Yea, that makes total sense. Worked perfectly! thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: counts going to be need to be moved outside the click handler as well ;)

Comment: ahh the joys of looking at a stale page :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do but in the second code snippet the interval is in a closure and it's not externally accessible. In the first example, it looks like interval is a global. I'm guessing when you call clearInterval in the AJAX call there is no interval variable available.